# RHEL5 with Apache 2.2.3; MySQL 5.0.77; PHP5.1.6

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, rhel5

Apologies if I'm asking an already asked question, but have searched and can't find any similar to this, so here goes.

I have RHEL5 running Apache 2.2.3 (prefork) with MySQL and PHP.
Up until a couple of days ago I was running MySQL 5.0.2, I mistakenly applied yum updates, which in turn gave me MySQL 5.0.77.
Ever since then, I've had a nightmare! The software I use behind Apache is bespoke, but requires MySQL and PHP. It is basically a web server written in PHP with a MySQL backend. It is verified as being ok with Apache 2.2.9; MySQL 5.0.5 and PHP 5.2.6 running on Debian Lenny.

At the moment my server is RHEL5 with Apache 2.2.3; MySQL 5.0.77; PHP 5.2.6.

Would I be right in thinking I need to upgrade my Apache to 2.2.9 to prevent errors such as this one when I try to start httpd
"/root/php-5.2.9/libs/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: zend_wrong_param_count"

If I ./configure with PHP5.1.6 I can get httpd to start, however I get loads of MySQL errors and not much of my web server works correctly.

A stumbling block for me is RHEL, I'm more used to DebianGNU linux as opposed to Redhat.

If anyone could help I would be really happy, thanks.

Comment: I am also wondering if I need to make clean Apache and MySQL before I re-make my PHP insall?
Basically I ran yum update, this gave me MySQL5.0.77. I am thinking maybe if I install Apache 2.2.9 this will work better with MySQL5.0.77 and PHP 5.2.9? My server is currently displaying MySQL errors when I access it via http. If I change my PHP up to 5.2.9 I can't get httpd to start so have dropped back to PHP5.1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your question specifically, however how you made sure you've run the command "**mysql-upgrade**". When I've upgraded MySQL on centos/rhel boxes in the past, after installing the packages I've needed to run this command (which may actually be "mysql-update" or similar, I'm writting this from memory), which goes through all your databases to make sure they are compatible with the new underlying version of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, if I connect to MySQL it does tell me that it's mysql 5.0.77, would I still need to update the actual database too?